# FATFS f_write and f_close inconsistent in execution speed

Tags: c, stm32, fwrite, fclose, fatfs

Using Systick to count how long each function takes in the process of writing data to an SD card (4 bit SDIO + DMA) from an STM32f411RE, I get a sporadic execution time on both the f_write and f_close functions.

Most of the time the f_write takes around 20 to 30ms to complete and the f_close around 5 to 10ms but occasionally, in  an app that does nothing but iteratively write dummy data to SD, these functions take over 300ms before immediately speeding up again on the next write iteration.

I'm thinking including code may not be necessary but here's the rough idea anyway:

```
if (f_mount(&myFatFS, SDPath, 1) == FR_OK)
   {mountTime = TimingDelay; //TimingDelay is counted using systick

   if (f_open(&myFile, myFileName, FA_WRITE | FA_OPEN_APPEND) == FR_OK)
      {
       fileOpenTime = TimingDelay;

       sprintf(data1,"dummy data 64kB in length"); 

       dataGenTime = TimingDelay;

       f_write(&myFile, data1, 64000, &myBytes); //write dummy data to chip

       writeTime = TimingDelay;

       f_close(&myFile);

       fileCloseTime = TimingDelay;
...etc
```

I'm using the differences in 'TimingDelay' which decrements on each systick interrupt, to calculate the time spent on each stage, for example `writeTime - fileCloseTime` gives the time taken to close the file; `f_close`.

the size of the dummy data char[] does not change.

Is FATFS just inherently unstable or is there a common practice that I am unaware of to stop the hiccups?

EDIT: I should mention using `f_sync()` instead of `f_close()` on each cycle yields a marginal improvement in average speed but it still suffers the same sporadic hesitations.

Comment: https://flashdba.com/2014/12/10/understanding-flash-unpredictable-write-performance/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is your problem, so I'm posting as a comment. It's likely this is just a matter of how the SD card works and has little to do with the fatfs (though how far tables are layed out might be contributing to how frequent this happens). While sd cards on average are decently fast (though cheaper ones can be pretty slow), they do occasionally take a while to do a write (since they have to erase a page to write to previously written to bytes, and also has to manage wear leveling to prevent bytes from becoming unusable). Might be worth probing the SD cmd line to see what's up.

Comment: does this happen on a cycle? as in do you write X times and then have your slow open/close and after that it's fast again?

Comment: @Unn After reading around the source that Hans provided I think you could be right. I'll get the scope out, cheers.

Comment: @TarickWelling No, it appears to be sporadic - non cyclical.